# Laravel API works locally but not on hosting server

Tags: laravel, api

These are my routes:

```
Route::post('get_client', 'API\ClientController@ShowClient');
Route::post('new_loans', 'API\LoanController@ShowNewLoans');
Route::post('new_loans/{BR_ID}', 'API\LoanController@ShowNewLoans');
```

`get_client`, but works locally on my personal computer:

```
public function ShowClient(Request $request) {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Okay'], 200);
}
```

Below works perfectly locally and on the server:

```
public function ShowNewLoans($BR_ID = null) {
    if ($BR_ID == null) {
        $newLoans = Loans::where([
            ['APPLICATION_NO', NULL],
            ['OL_TEMP_APP_NO', '!=', NULL],
            ['ActivityListID', '!=', 5]
        ])->get();
    } else {
        $newLoans = Loans::where([
            ['APPLICATION_NO', NULL],
            ['OL_TEMP_APP_NO', '!=', NULL],
            ['ActivityListID', '!=', 5],
            ['BR_ID', $BR_ID]
        ])->get();
    }

    if ($newLoans->isEmpty()) {
        return response()->json(["message" => "There are no online new loan applications found."], 204);
    } else {
        return response()->json($newLoans, 200);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? They both use the same namespace. The codes work perfectly in my computer but when its on my hosting server (Amazon EC2) it returns an error 500. These are the headers from postman:

```
Date
Thu, 21 May 2020 08:16:22 GMT

Server
Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.3.15

X-Powered-By
PHP/7.3.15

Cache-Control
no-cache, private

Content-Length
1750

Connection
close

Content-Type
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Set debug mode to true in .env file to see the error

Comment: or just check the log files so users don't get to see what error was? well your app looks like don't have any proper user till now changing debug mode might be the right choice for you

Comment: run `php artisan optimize:clear` and try again

Comment: @Vahid2015 Thank you, I forgot about that. My .env file in the production server was set debug to false, when I turned it to true it showed the error.